# ruby bundler openssl error

Tags: ruby, openssl, bundler

i have bundle 1.3.0, rubygems 2.00, ruby 1.9.3p392 with rvm 1.18.15 on a debian squeeze machine

when doing `bundle install` with the following sources in the Gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
                                                                                                                                                                                     source 'https://ourgemserver.ourcompany.com'`

I get

`.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in 'connect': 
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

while `gem install <one of the gems in gemfile>` works without any problems

I have tried putting the certificate from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem into .rvm/usr/ssl/cert.pem without any effect.

also, bundler doesn't seem to honor `:ssl_verify_mode: 0` in the user home's .gemrc

any further hints?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X 10.7.5, I solved the same error by updating openssl and adding the following to .bash_profile:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried `export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (the path comes from http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates), unfortunately no luck - same error still :(

Comment: What do you get from 'openssl version'?

Comment: `OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010` as it is a debian system. tried the rvm openssl as well (which is 1.0?)